# Same newly generated id used for both parent and child objects on original save

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a number of objects that all link to a parent table in a 1-2-1 manor.

Everything is 1-2-1 and all link to the root project table I have used the ProjectId as the primary key in some of the child tables.

In my code I'm having a problem with having the project id propagate down; parent --> child. I get an error stating "ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()" which I understand to mean that I cannot add the child class without a project ID, however this is one save() call.

Is it possible to save a object that contains child objects which all share the parent objects generated ID all at once? I feel it would be cleaner to create the object with all child objects and trigger save once instead of manually handling transactions because my only option at the moment is multiple saves, one on the parent and then manually setting the new ID into all the children and triggering another save.

Parent:

```java
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID projectId;

    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.ALL,
            }, mappedBy = "project")
    private AdditionalInformation additionalInformation;

    private String someField;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Child:

```java
public class AdditionalInformation {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID projectId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Project project;
    
    private String someData;


    //Getters and setters etc...
}
```

Test would read something like

```java
Project project = new project();

AdditionalInformation ai = new AdditionalInformation();

ai.setSomeData("Test set");

project.setAdditionalInformation(ai);
project.setSomeField("Test field set");

Project p = projectRepo.save(project);

assertEquals(p.getProjectId(), p.getAdditionalInformation.getProjectId());
```

Comment: Explain what you mean a bit more, but it sounds like your 'child' entities use the parent's ID as their own ID - but you have mapped the 'child' AdditionalInformation entity to have very separate fields; it has a foreign key "project_projectId" as well as its own "projectId" primary key column. Did you mean for it to only have a single "projectId" column used as both a foreign key and the ID?

Comment: Yes I intended for the table to have a single Pk which also is used as the FK to link to the project. Everything is project specific so I didn't see much point of having a second uuid. I'm happy for the table to generate its own ID field and have the projectId as a separate column if that's better/easier however at the moment my child table has a single column called projectId that is both PK and FK  which ideally would get the generated value from the parent on save

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mapping your ID field in the relationship so that JPA will set it for you based on the reference value? This is referred to as a derived ID, and there are a number of ways to do it based on what you need in your entity:

```
public class AdditionalInformation {

    @Id
    private UUID projectId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn("projectid")
    @MapsId
    private Project project;
    
    private String someData;


    //Getters and setters etc...
}
```

Or you can just mark the project as the ID:

```
public class AdditionalInformation {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn("projectid")
    private Project project;
    
    private String someData;

    //Getters and setters etc...
}
```

In both cases, you would use the UUID projectId value as the AdditionalInformation primary key for find by key lookups.